# How to Get The Taxonomy Term in Custom Post Type Loop Inside a Wp Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, terms

I need to get the **term** of each post while running WP Query. I tried this inside the loop

```
$term = $loop->get_queried_object();
echo  $term->name;
```

but I am still getting custom Post Type registered name instead of getting the Term!

```
$args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'services',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 8, 
        'orderby' => 'title', 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

     $term = $loop->get_queried_object();
     echo  $term->name; 

     echo  get_the_title(); 

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
//Edit Width post type
$categories = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'services');
$separator = ', ';
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
echo '<a class="cat_item" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( '%s', 'your-themes' ), $category->name ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>' . $separator;
}
}
endwhile;
```

You can try in loop

More in: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/